# Why am I getting this TypeError ARIMA.fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'disp'

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

This is my code:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA

arima = ARIMA(trend, order=(0,0,2))
arima_fit = arima.fit(disp=0)
plt.plot(ts)
plt.plot(arima_fit.fittedvalues, color='Red')
```

...And this is the resulting error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[42], line 4
      2 # fit model
      3 arima = ARIMA(trend, order=(0,0,2))
----> 4 arima_fit = arima.fit(disp=0)
      5 plt.plot(ts)
      6 plt.plot(arima_fit.fittedvalues, color='Red')

TypeError: ARIMA.fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'disp'
```

I tried updating and installing all the necessary python libraries but the error still persists. Anyone got any idea for this?

Comment: What leads you to think that method accepts that parameter?  The documentation doesn't say so.  https://www.statsmodels.org/0.8.0/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.html

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: Why are you using `disp=0`?  What's it's purpose?

Comment: Did you copy this code from somewhere?  You didn't answer my question -- why do you think this should work?